# Kotlin 1.5.0 & Junit with 5.7.1/5.8.0-M1 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, junit5

Gradle 7.0 & Kotlin 1.5.0 running gradle @ lines: 59-62. All refer with 'org.junit'.

```
testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.8.0-M1'
testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine', version: '5.8.0-M1'
testCompile group: 'org.junit.vintage', name: 'junit-vintage-engine', version: '5.8.0-M1'
testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-params', version: '5.8.0-M1'
```

Results in:

> gradle build clean
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file '/Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/GoStopHandle/build.gradle' line: 59
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'GoStopHandle'.
>
> > Could not find method testCompile() for arguments [{group=org.junit.jupiter, name=junit-jupiter-api, version=5.8.0-M1}]
> > on object of type
> > org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
> incompatible with Gradle 8.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
> individual deprecation warnings. See
> https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Comment: Please show your full Gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

`compile` and `testCompile` is deprecated and should be replaced with `implementation` and `testImplementation`

org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine specifically should use `testRuntimeOnly`